# I followed a youtube timelapse video to make same 3d model in blender, Can I use this in my game?

Tags: blender, copyright, licensing, 3d-modeling

I saw a youtube timelapse video about making a car 3d model, I liked it and followed the same, I design almost same looking model (90% same), Can I use this in my game?

There is no license mentioned on video, the creator of video has just written 'Just for fun' in description of youtube video.

**Update:**
As per my understanding if we download or copy/paste a copyrights protected asset, we will need permission of its author, but I am neither downloading nor copy pasting anything, I am simply just seeing a video and making something similar asset, so do I really need a permission of the video creator and however he hasn't mentioned any license term also in the video.

Comment: You might find this [earlier Q&A about copyright of content imitating a tutorial example](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/154995/39518) useful for your situation.

Comment: this is talking about whole game, I haven't followed any game tutorial and made the same, I have followed an asset making tutorial and made almost similar model, now can I use this in my game?

Comment: You'll get a lot more use out of StackExchange if you don't limit yourself to questions that are 100% identical to yours. Read the reasoning in the accepted answer as it applies to "derivative work" and you may find it sheds light on your situation as well.

Comment: The real question isn't about you following the steps in the video, you need to consider the car you are re-creating. Creating a recognisable replication of an existing product takes you into copyright/trademark infringement with the product manufacturer, not the tutorial maker.

Comment: @sambler Its not a real car model, just an innovative design, kind of concept car, I am not worried about any manufacturer, I am worried about tutorial maker, I tried contacting him, but didnt get any response.